# Error occurs infinitely on nuxt axios. What did I do wrong?

Tags: vue.js, axios, nuxt.js

I am currently working on a project with nuxt, and I communicate data with axios.

However, if an error occurs in Axios, it requests Axios indefinitely and stops.

If I make a wrong Axios request, I want an error return right away. What did I do wrong?

[image]

[image]

The error 'cannot read property 'length' of undefined' occurs at first. And there's an infinite number of errors 'cannot read property 'data' of undefined'

This is code written in plugin.

```js
import SecureLS from 'secure-ls'

export default function({ app, $axios, store }) {
  if (process.client) {
    const ls = new SecureLS({
      encodingType: 'aes',
      encryptionSecret: 'key'
    })
    $axios.defaults.timeout = 3000
    $axios.onRequest((config) => {
      if (ls.get('key')) {
        config.headers.common['X-Token'] = `token ${ls.get('key')}`
      }
    })
    $axios.onError((error) => {
      if (
        error.response.data &&
        error.response.data.detail === 'email confirmed required.'
      ) {
        app.router.push({ name: 'check' })
      }
    })
  }
}
```

Comment: Not sure about the `length` error but [other examples I've seen concerning Axios plugin error handling](https://axios.nuxtjs.org/extend.html) check for `error.response`, eg `if (error.response && error.response.data && error.response.data.detail...`